# Python socket.recv returns corrupt address

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ipv6

In my "simple" ping utility for python 3, I suddenly started running into this weird error after a refactor. I managed to track down the problem to a corrupt address being returned by a socket's `recv` function. This is more or less the smallest I could make this code, which is meant to send an ICMPv6 echo request.

```
import struct
from myPingModule import IPv6_checksum as check

def doit():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_RAW, proto=58)
    sock.settimeout(7)

    raddr = socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, "2607:f8b0:400f:801::200e")
    laddr = socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, sock.getsockname()[0])

    header = struct.pack("!BBHHH", 0x80, 0,0,0,0)
    checksum = check(header, laddr, raddr)
    header = struct.pack("!BBHHH", 0x80, 0, checksum, 0,0)

    sock.sendto(header+bytes(41), ("2607:f8b0:400f:801::200e", 1)) #icmp has no notion of port numbers

    pkt, addr = sock.recvfrom(65536)

    print(pkt)
    print(addr)

    sock.close()
```

Now, when I run this function I get the following output:

```
b"\x86\x00;\x86@\x00\x07\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x06\xf6\xeb\\\xc0\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\xdc\x03\x04@\xc0\x00'\x8d\x00\x00\t:\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x01\x05X\x14\x18\x00I\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
('fe80::206:f6ff:feeb:5cc0%en0', 0, 0, 12)
```

So nested in there is `b':\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00`, which is my header preceded by the icmpv6 protocol number (`b':' == 58`) which normally would make me think there's something wrong with the packet I sent. However, the `IPv6_checksum` function went unchanged from a working state during the refactor, and I can't find any valid icmpv6 type/code combinations that would make sense in the received packet.

`nslookup` confirms that there's no record for `fe80::206:f6ff:feeb:5cc0%en0`, and `ping6` loses all packets it sends to that address. Plus it's clearly invalid based on the format.

What happened? What is this address? It's consistently the address that responds when I ping out to `2607:f8b0:400f:801::200e` (which is google.com), so it's not just a fluke. If my packets are malformed, why doesn't the response seem to indicate that?

### Update:

Today the problem has miraculously disappeared after my having changed nothing and written no new code. I can only surmise that this was some kind of bizarre, temporary network condition related to my specific machine or router. I still don't understand why this happened or what the response means, so I'm going to leave the question open for posterity.

Comment: It's a link-local address from the network connected to interface en0.

Comment: Why did I get a reply from a link-local address? I can `ping6 google.com` just fine, so it's not as if it failed to find a route to the host and responded in some unusual fashion

Comment: Is that a router advertisement?!

Comment: It really looks like it. It's possible that I just happened to be listening when a new router joined the network, and honestly idk what else could've happened.